# Sound as an energy source

Tags: energy, waves, acoustics, phonons

A sound wave is a massless packet of energy much like a photon. Would it be feasible to use these energy packets to generate electricity in the same way as solar panels. I am thinking of panels about the size of solar panels with a thousand microphones arranged in rows. These could be placed in areas that produce a lot of continuous  sound such as waves breaking on a beach.

Comment: A [_dynamic microphone_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Dynamic), available wherever electric musical instruments are sold, converts acoustic energy into electrical energy. A [_piezoelectric_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Piezoelectric) microphone does the same though, I'm _guessing_ that a piezo mic might be a lot less efficient. But, ditto what Bob D said in the answer below: If some source of noise is not loud enough to actually kill you, then you may be disappointed by how little power it actually carries.

Answer (score 1):

> A sound wave is a massless packet of energy much like a photon.

Sound is nothing like a photon. It is an acoustic wave (not an "energy packet") requiring a transmission medium such as a gas liquid or solid. Photons require no medium to travel.

> Would it be feasible to use these energy packets to generate
> electricity in the same way as solar panels.

Sound energy can be converted into a source of electricity by means of a suitable transducer converting the vibrations of sound (variations in air pressure) into electrical energy. A simple example of such a transducer is the microphone.  It is an entirely different mechanism then generating electricity from solar panels.

> What I am wondering is how much electrical energy could be produced.
> Waves breaking on a beach happens day and night.

To quote from the following MIT website: https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/can-sound-be-converted-to-useful-energy/

"There is definitely energy in sound...But the density of the energy is very low, and there is no way to capture it all. You'd have to have obscenely loud, continuous sound for harvesting to be worthwhile"

Hope this helps

Comment: What I am wondering is how much electrical energy could be produced. Waves breaking on a beach happens day and night.

Comment: See update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

An example of what you are talking about is a [sound powered telephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound-powered_telephone)

The microphone of a standard landline telephone is a type of microphone that must be powered in order for the microphone to generate a signal. But is it also possible to use a type of microphone design that is referred to as [Dynamic microphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Dynamic)

A dynamic microphone has the same type of parts as a loudspeaker, and its mode of operation is the reverse of how a loudspeaker operates.

Our human hearing is exquisitely sensitive to sound; the amount of sound energy we need to meet the threshold for hearing is amazingly small.

A level of sound that is loud to human hearing still involves only a small amount of sound pressure energy. Even if there would technology to harvest sound energy at high efficiency, it would still only be a very small amount.

In the other answer here there is already a link to the page on the MIT website 'Ask an engineer':  [Can sound be converted to useful energy?](https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/can-sound-be-converted-to-useful-energy/)

> What the human ear perceives as clanging cacophony — the roar of a train engine or the whine of a pneumatic drill — only translates to about a hundredth of a watt per square meter.

Well, loudspeakers for consumer have a power requirement in the order of 50 or a 100 Watts. Clearly the efficiency of power transfer from the speaker to the air is abysmally low. I presume: the only reason it sounds so powerful is because our hearing is so sensitive.